# Wait until Text to Speech is speaking

Tags: android, text-to-speech

In my app I'm using TTS. Often I need to wait until TTS ends speaking so I put a while loop in my speak function :

```
 protected void speakOut(String text) {

    tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);

    while (tts.isSpeaking() ) {
    };
}
```

but if I press volume keys during it, the app crashes, becouse the main thread is blocked into the loop.

Maybe I could use UtteranceProgressListener but the operations that follow the speakOut() are always different, so the onDone() method should be different each time...

There's a way to resolve this issue?

I'm sorry if I wrote/ I will write heresies but I'm almost newbie in Android programming!

Comment: Use the UtteranceProgressListener as you said and pass in a variable as the UtteranceId - That id will correspond to the action you want to do onDone() - You could use integers and a case switch statement or Strings and match them.

Comment: Let me know if you want some pseudo code

Comment: I would have to handle too many cases....I solve the issue simply executing speakOut() in a new thread!!

Answer (score 2):

Try to use progress bar dialog. i think that might will work. and set it

```
ProgressDialog pdialog = new ProgressDialog(yourActivity.this);
pdialog.setMessage("loading");
pdialog.setCancelable(false);

protected void speakOut(String text) {
    pdialog.show();
    tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);

    while (tts.isSpeaking() ) {
    };
    pdialog.cancel();
}
```

Try this.it might work..... :)

Comment: Thanks for your help but it doesn't work :( No Progress Dialog is displayed (maybe I'm doing something wrong?!), and the app still crashes.. besides I would like to adjust the volume while tts is speaking.